# Why does <a> tag give a different output from <li> tag when applying a hover background?

Tags: css, html

[Link to my jsfiddle work](https://jsfiddle.net/c3bp7kgx/)

I switched my "navbar" from a basic header navigation bar to a custom layout. 
I changed my li tags to an a tag to include classes and separate css designs.

Following this change, my link didn't change colors when I hovered over them.
Is there a reason as to why this would occur when I include classes in my tags.

```css
.tl,
.tc,
.tr,
.bl,
.bc,
.br {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Bungee Shade;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
  position: fixed;
}

.tl {
  top: 45px;
  left: 60px;
}

.tc {
  margin-top: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 50%;
}

.tr {
  margin-top: 45px;
  right: 60px;
}

.bl {
  bottom: 45px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.bc {
  bottom: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 50%;
}

.br {
  bottom: 45px;
  right: 60px;
}

.tl:hover,
.tc:hover,
.tr:hover,
.bl:hover,
.bc:hover,
.br:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="tl" href="#">HOME</a> 
  <a class="tc" href="#">MUSIC</a>
  <a class="tr" href="#">BIO</a>
  <a class="bl" href="#">TOUR</a>
  <a class="bc" href="#">SHOP</a>
  <a class="br" href="#">TSA</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add some padding, or some dimensions, on the a tag classes (not on the hover state) and see if it works. a tags work inline so if they have no dimensions, they have no background.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the `position:relative` and `z-index` to your `navbar` as your slider is currently overlapping it. so `hover` is not happening on `a` tag

```css
* {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;

 
 /*background-image: url(test.JPG);*/ 
}


.navbar{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

 
.tl, .tc, .tr, .bl, .bc, .br{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: green;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: Bungee Shade;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 10px;
 transition: .5s; 
 position: fixed; 
}

.tl{
 top: 45px;
 left: 60px;
}

.tc{
 margin-top: 45px;
 text-align: center;
 right: 50%;
}

.tr{
 margin-top: 45px;
 right: 60px;
}

.bl{
 bottom: 45px;
 margin-left: 60px;
}

.bc{
 bottom: 45px;
 text-align: center;
 right: 50%;
}

.br{
 bottom: 45px;
 right: 60px;
}

.tl:hover, .tc:hover, .tr:hover, .bl:hover, .bc:hover, .bl:hover{
 background-color: orange;
}




 #slider, .wrap, .slide-content{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Bungee Shade ;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh; 
 overflow-x: hidden; 
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

.wrap{position:relative;}

.slide{
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide1{background-image: url('img/goho.jpg');
width: 330px;
height: 330px;
left: 33.3%;
margin-top: 12%;
position: fixed;

}

.slide2{background-image: url('');


}
.slide3{background-image: url('');}


.slide-content{
/*Text in the middle*/ 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
}

.slide-content span{
 font-size: 15px; /*rem*/
 color: black;
}

.arrow{
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -30px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
}

#arrow-left{
 border-width: 30px 40px 30px 0;
 border-color: transparent #000 transparent transparent;
 left: 0;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

#arrow-right{
 border-width: 30px 0 30px 40px;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
 right: 0;
 margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
 <a class="tl" href="#">HOME</a>
 <a class="tc" href="music.htm">MUSIC</a>
 <a class="tr" href="#">BIO</a>
 <a class="bl" href="#">TOUR</a>
 <a class="bc" href="#">SHOP</a>
 <a class="br" href="#">TSA</a>
</div>


<div class ="wrap">
 <div id="arrow-left" onclick="slideLeft()" class="arrow"></div>
 <div id="slider">
 <div class="slide slide1">
   <div class="slide-content"></div> 
  </div>
 <div class="slide slide2">
   <div class="slide-content"></div> 
  </div>

  
 <div id="arrow-right" onclick="slideRight()" class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh so the `hover` was happening below the slider. Thank you.